# Need a quick and simple classic asp page to query records from a sql server database

Tags: asp-classic

I know this seems elementary, but I have been looking for 2 days and all i find is snippets that dont work. I am simply trying to have a web page dynamically display the contents of a table with 4 columns.
Need by tomorrow!
Help!
Thank you!

Comment: The question is considered rude: a) it fails to demonstrate effort on your part you should at least include some code that you have tried with some description of what problem you are having and b) "Need by tomorrow" implies that perhaps we should give your question more attention than others.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simplest way to do it.  This is assuming your server is SQL Server.  If not, head to http://connectionstrings.com and look up the specifics for your server. That site is awesome and I find myself on it all the time.

```
set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
rs.open "select col1 from table1", "provider=sqloledb.1;uid=user;pwd=password;database=database;Server=server;"
do while rs.EOF = false
    response.write rs("col1")
    rs.MoveNext
loop
```

What's going on here is we're using Microsoft's ADO database library.  I'm creating a `Recordset` object and calling its `open` method.  Provided to the `open` method are the sql statement I want to execute and the specifics on how to connect to that database.  The specifics on how to connect to the database is commonly referred to as a "Connection String."  The site mentioned above is an invaluable resource in figuring out exactly what this should look like.  99% of the time, any problems I've run into have been an invalid connection string.  Once opened, I loop through the returned records in the while loop and write out the data to the page.

DON'T FORGET THE CALL TO `rs.MoveNext`!!!  I've done this a handful of times over the years and you'll wind up with an infinite loop.

Comment: You have already proven to be an invalable resource, thank you so much. You see I am a DBA and havent touched this stuff in over 6 years. Do i need any more code to make it display properly when hitting it through a web browser? i am going to http://localhost/yourfile.asp and it returns a webpage with the source code in one long string.

Comment: You have a problem with your IIS config.  The page isn't getting passed through the asp interpreter.  Make sure classic asp is installed/enabled.  Here's a guide on how to do this. http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/562/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis/